# Netbeans 12 on Windows, Console not outputting System.out.print

Tags: netbeans

Running the following simple program in Netbeans 12 and finding that the print statements won't display until after all data is entered - so there is no prompting before the input request. When using println, it works as expected.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
    String firstName = in.next();

    System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
    String lastName = in.next();
    
    System.out.print("Enter age: ");
    int age = in.nextInt();
    
    System.out.printf("%-16s%-16s%-16s%n", "First Name", "Last Name", "Age");
    System.out.printf("%-16s%-16s%-16s%n", firstName, lastName, age);
```

Comment: Does `print()` work if you add a `System.out.flush()` after each `print()`?

Comment: I tried a flush after each print - it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: This same code works on InelliJ - is there a workaround for NetBeans that I'm missing? Google didn't help.

Comment: No, idea. It works for me. Does using `nextLine()` change anything?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for engaging in this -- nextLine doesn't work either. I've also duplicated this issue on another computer.

Comment: There is [a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4453) logged for this. From the description it seems this relates to using Maven. I tested with a "classic" Ant based project. What are you using? Ant or Maven? [This issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4617) mentions that IntelliJ had a similar issue not long ago ;)

Comment: Yes, I'm using Maven. I just confirmed that the trouble with print is not an issue in Ant. Wow, surprised that this bug exists. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name - much appreciated.

Comment: To close on this... The print issue occurs in both Maven and Gradle project, but not Ant. Hopefully there will be fix soon - the type of program you see above is used in intro courses -- having a bug for such simple code will contribute to driving new programmers to other IDE's.