# Observed print() v println() differences between NetBeans IDE 12 v IDE 11.3

Tags: netbeans, printing, println

The following code works in NetBeans 11.3 but hangs in NetBeans 12 -- any ideas why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewMain
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Price of item: ");
        double price = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Price = " + price);
        }
    }
```

I'm running both NetBeans versions on a 2019 iMac ios 10.15.8. Additionally, this has also been observed in many different Windows configurations running NetBeans 12.

Note: The code will run on both NetBeans 11.3 and 12 IF the code is changed from print() to println() methods.

Thanks for any answers,

Tedd

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a known issue, see Jira issue [NETBEANS-4453](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-4453).

Comment: This seems to only impact Maven projects. Also see StackOverflow entry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687672/netbeans-12-on-windows-console-not-outputting-system-out-print