# java.util.Scanner not working on NetBeans 12.3

Tags: java.util.scanner

I just downloaded Netbeans 12.3 to follow along with a tutorial on Java. However, the main class won't run.

There isn't any error in the output. It just shows "scanning for projects..." The status of the blue Run bar below the output window does not progress.

Note that the code works fine in Eclipse.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687672/netbeans-12-on-windows-console-not-outputting-system-out-print) resolved my issue. It seems to be a bug peculiar to Maven.

Thank you,